# Стилизация формы в DLL [Delphi, VCLStyles]

Tags: delphi, dll, style, forms, vcl

Имеется программа на Delphi с VCLStyles. К ней подключается DLL на Delphi с формами. Требуется чтобы формы из DLL имели тот-же стиль, что и основная программа. Вопрос уже поднимался на английской версии [How can I apply Delphi XE2 skins to forms in a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335976/how-can-i-apply-delphi-xe2-skins-to-forms-in-a-dll)
Каким образом правильно передать/подключить этот StyleServices?

Comment: А чем ответ по вашей ссылке не устраивает?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов отсутствием конкретики. Что я только уже не делал с этим StyleServices - толка ноль. Пару кусков кода как передать из EXE и как принять в DLL решило бы мою проблему. В гугле был. Везде аналогично неполный ответ.

Comment: Спасайте, люди добрые. Не хочется с собой BPL таскать. С ним работает, как на зло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему двумя способами:

1. EXE и DLL с галкой Link with runtime packages - один существенный недостаток - BPL с собой таскать
2. Из EXE передаём информацию об установленной теме (откуда брать), в DLL устанавливаем тему откуда сказали. Главный косяк с окнами типа MessageBox - решается путём добавления в DLL(!) следующего кода:

   ```
   uses Vcl.Themes, Vcl.Styles, Vcl.SysStyles, ...;
   ...
   TStyleManager.SetStyle(...);//Установка стиля
   TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterSysStyleHook('#32770',TSysDialogStyleHook);//Убираем хук
   ```

А лучше сразу снимать системные хуки, т.к. будет краш с меню и прочим

```
    TStyleManager.SystemHooks := [];
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I recommend making a small addition, just add a line with the listed style resources to the ".dproj" file of the project, and then the library will be assembled normally and work with your styles already!

Comment: В сообществе Stack Overflow на русском принято давать ответы на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш ответ на русский!